# SPI raspberry pi (master) & arduino due (slave)

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, spi, wiringpi, arduino-due

I'm trying to communicate raspi and due with SPI.
Raspi is master and due is slave.
I can send bytes from raspi to due via SPI with no problem.
But what I need on DUE side is , when I received the data from Raspi I send a new data to Raspi from DUE.
Here are my codes;

Raspi QT wiring pi (master)

```
#include <wiringPiSPI.h>
#include <QDebug>
#define SPI_CHANNEL 0
#define SPI_CLOCK_SPEED 500000

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    int fd = wiringPiSPISetupMode(SPI_CHANNEL, SPI_CLOCK_SPEED, 0); // Starting SPI
    if (fd == -1) {
        qDebug() << "Failed to init SPI communication.\n";
        return -1;
    }
    qDebug() << "SPI communication successfully setup.\n";


    unsigned char buf[2] = { 1, 2 }; // Char for sending to DUE
    wiringPiSPIDataRW(SPI_CHANNEL, buf, 2); // Sending and receiving data
    qDebug() << "Data returned: " << buf[0] << buf[1] << "\n";
    return a.exec();
}
```

Arduino DUE codes(slave)

```
void setup() {
Serial.begin(250000);
//SPI serial recieve
REG_PMC_PCER0 |= PMC_PCER0_PID24;      // Power up SPI clock
REG_SPI0_WPMR = 0<<SPI_WPMR_WPEN;   //Unlock user interface for SPI

//Instance SPI0, MISO: PA25, (MISO), MOSI: PA26, (MOSI), SCLK: PA27, (SCLK), NSS: PA28, (NPCS0)
REG_PIOA_ABSR |= PIO_ABSR_P25;    // Transfer Pin control from PIO to SPI
REG_PIOA_PDR |= PIO_PDR_P25;        // Set MISO pin to an output

REG_PIOA_ABSR |= PIO_ABSR_P26;    // Transfer Pin control from PIO to SPI
REG_PIOA_PDR |= 0<<PIO_PDR_P26;  // Set MOSI pin to an input

REG_PIOA_ABSR |= PIO_ABSR_P27;     // Transfer Pin control from PIO to SPI
REG_PIOA_PDR |= 0<<PIO_PDR_P27;   // Set SCLK pin to an input

REG_PIOA_ABSR |= PIO_ABSR_P28;     // Transfer Pin control from PIO to SPI
REG_PIOA_PDR |= 0<<PIO_PDR_P28;   // Set NSS pin to an input

REG_SPI0_CR = 1;   // Enable SPI
REG_SPI0_MR = 0;   // Slave mode
// Receive Data Register Full Interrupt
SPI0->SPI_IER = SPI_IER_RDRF;
NVIC_EnableIRQ(SPI0_IRQn);

SPI0->SPI_CSR[0] = SPI_CSR_NCPHA|SPI_CSR_BITS_8_BIT;
}

void SPI0_Handler()
{    
  byte c = SPI0->SPI_RDR;
  SPI0->SPI_TDR = c;
}
```

With these codes I can send chars from Raspberry to DUE successfully but can only receive "0 0" from DUE. 
But If I connect the MOSI and MISO pins together on Raspberry pi I cant successfully receive/return "1 2"

EDIT :
I changed the arduino DUE with arduino MEGA and use the "SLAVE" sketch on gammon... [GAMMON SLAVE SKETCH](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=10892&reply=2#reply2)
Of course no change on raspberry side and everything works succesfully.
So the problem is on DUE side....

Answer (score 0):

I check the due datasheet. 
The register has some error. You can try this:

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    while(!Serial);

    //SPI serial recieve
    REG_PMC_PCER0 |= PMC_PCER0_PID24;       // Power up SPI clock
    REG_SPI0_WPMR = 0<<SPI_WPMR_WPEN;       //Unlock user interface for SPI

    //Instance SPI0, MISO: PA25, (MISO), MOSI: PA26, (MOSI), SCLK: PA27, (SCLK), NSS: PA28, (NPCS0)
    REG_PIOA_ABSR &= ~PIO_ABSR_P25;         // Transfer Pin control from PIO to SPI
    REG_PIOA_PDR |= PIO_PDR_P25;            // disable pio to control this pin (MOSI)

    REG_PIOA_ABSR &= ~PIO_ABSR_P26;         // Transfer Pin control from PIO to SPI
    REG_PIOA_PDR |= PIO_PDR_P26;            // disable pio to control this pin (MOSI)

    REG_PIOA_ABSR &= ~PIO_ABSR_P27;         // Transfer Pin control from PIO to SPI
    REG_PIOA_PDR |= PIO_PDR_P27;            // disable pio to control this pin (SCLK)

    REG_PIOA_ABSR &= ~PIO_ABSR_P28;         // Transfer Pin control from PIO to SPI
    REG_PIOA_PDR |= PIO_PDR_P28;            //disable pio to control this pin (NSS)

    REG_SPI0_CR = 1;                        // Enable SPI
    REG_SPI0_MR = 0;                        // Slave mode

    SPI0->SPI_IER = SPI_IER_RDRF;           //Receive Data Register Full Interrupt
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(SPI0_IRQn);

    SPI0->SPI_CSR[0] = SPI_CSR_NCPHA|SPI_CSR_BITS_8_BIT;    // Shift on falling edge and transfer 8 bits.
    Serial.println("START");
}

bool flag=false;
uint16_t DataReceived;
void SPI0_Handler()
{
    uint32_t status = SPI0->SPI_SR;
    if (status & SPI_SR_RDRF){
        DataReceived = SPI0->SPI_RDR & SPI_RDR_RD_Msk;
        flag=true;
    }
    if (status & SPI_SR_TDRE) {
        SPI0->SPI_TDR = (uint16_t)DataReceived;
    }
}

void loop() {
    if(flag){
        flag=false;
        Serial.println(DataReceived);
    }
}
```